# AWS linux hosting multiple projects in single instance nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Hi in my project I've 3 sub projects.

1. NodeJs Rest API
2. Admin panel VueJs Single Page App
3. Normal website VueJs Single Page App

I did

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

then I changed default server block to

[image]

Now this works fine. But how could I add another two? (Two vuetify UIs)
Is it okay to create another server block like this in the same `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

Basically instead of having one default website, we can create multiple server block files one per each site.

Reference:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Hope this helps